# Best approach regarding to get least amount of lock time when reading/writing to access DB

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I have a project where i am to syncronize a MS Access DB with a MySQL DB and i was wondering about best approach to read/write from/to the MS Access DB since it will lock the DB while i do it.
(There will be other applications reading/writing to the same Access DB so i would like to minimize the amount of time i lock it).

Does the language i choose make difference? I am most used to writing applications using C# and .NET.

Anyone more experienced out there with recommendations/experiences?

Comment: Is the sync between the Access db and MySQL one way?

Comment: Can't you just copy the access DB and synchronize from the copy? How will you handle changes that happen during synchronization anyway?

Comment: The sync will be both ways, i could copy the access DB if that is the best way to avoid any changes during syncronization but i would get doing a select * from it and then working offline with data would be better? The access DB is only about 3-10MB in size so its not super big

Comment: What is the nature of the synchronization? Copying entire records to/from either database? Based on row IDs?  Or updating fields in existing rows?  If you're updating rows, you could do row-level locking. You could add small groups of records at a time as well. One approach is to create a cursors/recordsets with the changed records in both environments, and updating the target tables in small increments, only a few records per iteration.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a live syncronization, like SQL Server Replication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

Store the queries your application will use exclusively for lookup purposes in the Access DB and as ReadOnly in the query properites.  Then have your application query those ReadOnly queries, which will prevent unnecessary locks.

Keeping your update and insert SQL statements in the application short and simple will limit lock time to some extent as well.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the language matters much - you can use C# or VB in a .NET environment. Are you planning a real-time synchronization or an off-hours (lets say daily) synchronization of the two databases?

One approach for the synchronization would be to do a data dump of the tables to a text file, load them into properly indexed tables and then find updated records (using data access queries) and find new records (with an outer join) and append them to the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your table do not contains primary key. Add one, let's name it "Id"
2. Create table "sync_log" to store changes.

   - one column for "SQL" to apply to target DB.
   - one column for this "SQL"'s execute status. (pending, finished)
   - one column for time of this "SQL", then you can apply the SQLs in original order to target DB.
3. Create Trigger for Create,Update,Delete

   **crate:**
   when create one row, your trigger will insert following line to another table "sync_log"

   "INSERT into table T values(CA, CB, CC, CD)"

   **delete:**
   when create one row, your trigger will insert following line to another table "sync_log"

   "delete from table T where Id = 99"

   **update:** is similar, also identify target row by primary key "Id"
4. Let your app to poll the table "sync_log", apply new "pending" SQL to target DB, then update the SQL's status in "sync_log" to "finished".

This is one way sync, the another way sync is similar.

if (you are using Microsoft Access project)
 then 
{http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/create-a-trigger-adp-HP003085415.aspx }
else 
 { Access macro events is similar to trigger. http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx
}